# C - Cómo pedir al usuario que ingrese datos en un ciclo?

Tags: c, bucles

Necesito ayuda con un programa escrito en `C`. El programa debe calcular el  **sueldo** para **n empleado**. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
 printf ( "Ingrese la cantidad de empleados : " );
                   scanf ( "%d", &N );
                      for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    printf ( "Ingrese los datos del empleado %d\n", ( i + 1 ) );
    printf ( "Nombre: " );
    scanf ( "%c", E[i].nombre );
    printf ( "\n" );
    }
                   printf("\n Digite los años que ha eleaborado el trabajador:");
                   scanf("%d",&ano);
   if(ano > 10)
{
       printf(" Se le aplicara un diez por ciento.");
       printf(" El importe neto es de :%d", resul=40000*0.10);        
}
 else if ((ano < 10) && (ano > 5)) {
    printf("\n Se le aplicara un siete por ciento.");
       printf("\n El importe neto es de :%.2d", resul=40000*0.7);
       }  
        else if ((ano < 5) && (ano > 3)){
    printf("\n Se le aplicara un cinco por ciento.");
       printf("\n El importe neto es de :%.2d", resul=40000*0.5);
       }  
         else if (ano < 3){
    printf("\n Se le aplicara un tres por ciento.");
       printf("\n El importe neto es de :%.2d", resul=40000*0.5);
       }
```

Al recorrer el ciclo que pide el segundo nombre, no me pide el nombre, solo me pide los años. Cómo hago para que me pida el nombre y el año dentro del ciclo?

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que quieres hacer, el código de por si tiene varios errores, en el for solo estas pidiendo n veces el nombre, todo lo demas esta fuera del cuerpo de for, revisa bien las llaves.
Para leer un String (cadena de caracteres) se debe usar "%s" , usando "%c" solo lees el primer caracter que ingresas.
Podrias editar la pregunta con el codigo entero, y si es muy largo especificar mas las cosas porque por lo visto estas usando una estructura que tiene año y nombre.
Cuando pides la cantidad de empleados tendrias que reservar la memoria para todos esos empleados

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es `E[i].nombre`? Estaría bien que pusieses la declaración de la estructura y de las variables involucradas

Answer (score 1):

El problema de que no te pida el nombre al recorrer de nuevo el bucle, es porque en el *buffer* de entrada queda residuo, lo ultimo que introduces es un numero entero, por lo que al volver a pedir una cadena de texto, recoge el *enter* anterior al introducir los años e ignora la entrada de datos al nombre del 2º empleado.

```
 for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     printf ("Ingrese los datos del empleado %d\n", (i + 1));
     printf ("Nombre: ");
     scanf ("%c", E[i].nombre);
     printf ("\n");
 }

 printf("\n Digite los años que ha eleaborado el trabajador:");
 scanf("%d",&ano);
 fflush(stdin); //Limpiar *buffer* del teclado
```

Únicamente con añadir `fflush(stdin)` después de introducir los años debería funcionar y podrás introducir el nombre del siguiente empleado.

**EDIT**

Como ya se comentó esto que pongo es una mala practica, ya que `fflush` solo debe usarse con dispositivos de salida y `stdin` es un dispositivo de entrada.

Lo correcto seria que a la hora de recoger el dato con `scanf("%d",&ano);` se dejara un espacio en blanco detrás de `" %d"`.

Así quedaría.

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf ("Ingrese los datos del empleado %d\n", (i + 1));
    printf ("Nombre: ");
    scanf ("%c", E[i].nombre);
    printf ("\n");
 }

 printf("\n Digite los años que ha elaborado el trabajador:");
 scanf(" %d",&ano); // <-- Dejar espacio en blanco detrás de "%d"
```

Comment: Mola eso de enseñar malas prácticas desde el principio... `fflush` **solo** debe usarse con dispositivos **de salida**  y `stdin` es un dispositivo de entrada. Revisa la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/): *"In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (but this is not portable expected behavior)."*

Comment: Podría servir mejor la funcion fpurge(stdin) @eferion?? [fpurge](http://www.codecogs.com/library/computing/c/stdio.h/fflush.php?alias=fpurge)

Comment: No forma parte del estándar, así que si no te especifican que están trabajando en Linux tendrías que, o bien indicar expresamente que la solución solo es válida en Linux o proporcionar una solución específica para, al menos, Windows. C es así de *bonito*

Comment: Por otro lado el código tiene más errores a parte de la comentada basura en el buffer de entrada...pero si no completa la pregunta va a ser dificil responder de forma correcta

Comment: Esperemos pues... gracias por tus comentarios @eferion, es un placer aprender algo mas cada día.

Comment: No intentaba hecharte la bronca con lo de `fflush`, lo malo es que es una práctica tan generalizada que hasta se permiten el lujo de *enseñarla* en las universidades...

Comment: No me lo tomé a mal sinceramente, es cierto que son malas practicas, pero me pasó algo parecido y me enseñaron ese "truco"

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77451/discussion-between-eferion-and-mario-guiber).

Answer (score 0):

> Cómo hago para que me pida el nombre y el año dentro del ciclo?

Me imagino que lo que buscas es hacer un bucle donde el numero de N te pida por orden esto:

```
         1- nombre
         2- antigüedad
         3- a pagar
```

Si es así, date cuenta donde termina tu bucle `for`. Justo antes de entrar en el condicional `if`.

A ti te interesa introducir dentro del for todo hasta el fin de los bucles condicionales.

```
printf ( "Ingrese la cantidad de empleados : " );
scanf ( "%d", &N );
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    printf ( "Ingrese los datos del empleado %d\n", ( i + 1 ) );
    printf ( "Nombre: " );
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ( "%c", E[i].nombre );
    printf ( "\n" );
    printf("\n Digite los años que ha eleaborado el trabajador:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&ano);
   
    if(ano > 10){
       printf(" Se le aplicara un diez por ciento.");
       printf(" El importe neto es de :%d", resul=40000*0.10);        

    }else if ((ano < 10) && (ano > 5)){
       printf("\n Se le aplicara un siete por ciento.");
       printf("\n El importe neto es de :%.2d", resul=40000*0.7);
       
    }else if ((ano < 5) && (ano > 3)){
       printf("\n Se le aplicara un cinco por ciento.");
       printf("\n El importe neto es de :%.2d", resul=40000*0.5);
       
    }else if (ano < 3){
       printf("\n Se le aplicara un tres por ciento.");
       printf("\n El importe neto es de :%.2d", resul=40000*0.5);
       }
   } //final for.
```